# Regular Expression Group not ending with a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of names and their dob

```
1.uzamaki/narutomr 20mar
2.hyuga/hinata mrs 13apr
3.haruno/sakuramiss 25nov
4.uchiha/sasuke mstr
5.uchiha/itachi akatsuki mr 12feb
6.lee/rock 23jun
7.hatake/kakashi mr 30oct 8.sarutobi/hiruzen mr 31dec
```

And I need to extract the serial number, firstname, surname, title and dob;

for example in case number 5

```
number      -> 5
surname     -> uchiha
firstname   -> itachi akatsuki
title       -> mr
dob         -> 12feb
```

The regex I came up with

```
/(?<number>\d+)\.(?<surname>[a-z\s]*)\/(?<firstname>[a-z\s]*)(?<title>mrs|mr|miss|mstr)?\s(?<dob>\d{2}[a-z]{3})/giU
```

This works fine in Ungreedy mode, but lines which does not have the dob it fails. If I try to make the dob optional by adding a '?', none of the pattern matches completely.

So, is it possible to have the firstname group not ending with a title? Can $ be used just in the scope of the group?

I have cooked up a test here http://regex101.com/r/gR7tX2/4

*Note: Title and dob are optional groups. Also there may or may not be a space between the firstname and the title. Thus valid firstnames ending with a title are special cases and are out of scope of this quest.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<number>\d+)\.(?<surname>[a-z\s]+)/(?<firstname>[a-z\s]+)\s*(?<title>mrs?|miss|mstr)?(?:\s(?<dob>\d{2}[a-z]{3}))?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gR7tX2/3)

---

**Update:** Based on your edits you can use this regex:

```
(?<number>\d+)\.(?<surname>[a-z\s]+)/(?<firstname>[a-z\s]+)\s*(?<title>mrs?|miss|mstr)?(?:\s(?<dob>\d{2}[a-z]{3}))? *(?=\d+\.|$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/gR7tX2/5)

**PS:** Used flags are `miU` (multiline, ignore case, ungreedy)

Comment: Thank you for your response!

That works great but we cant have a $ at the end (my bad, will update the question with an additional test case), as there could be multiple names in a single line.

Also could you explain what is this wrapper group over dob?

Comment: Unless I make <firstname> non-greedy, it does not capture <title> separately  **(?<firstname>[a-z\s]+?)**

Comment: But in my demo2 I can see `title` bing captured everywhere.

Comment: @anubhava wow! you are a regex ninja, I got lost at the trailing positive look ahead, could you give me an explanation of that.

Comment: @anubhava I see that now. I think that is because of the "U" (ungreedy) modifier at Demo2 (which was not set by default in my tester). I would suggest commenting on that in your answer, or making <firstname> lazy.

Comment: Alright I made a note of **U (ungreedy) modifier** in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern but without the ugly U modifier:

```
~(?<number>[0-9]+) \.
 (?<surname>[a-z\s]+) / 
 (?<firstname>[a-z\s]+?) 
 (?: \s+ (?<title>m(?:rs?|iss|str)) )?
 (?: \s+ (?<dob>[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}) )?
 (?=\s[0-9]+\.|$)
~x
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ0tJ3/4)

The only useful non-greedy quantifier is in the firstname group, the goal is to trim the trailing spaces without "eating" the title. Since the two next groups are optional, you need to add a lookahead at the end to pump the non-greedy quantifier until the end of the item or the title or dob part.

Comment: This fails test case 1 and 3 where the title is the part of the firstname. But interesting breakup of the firstname, let me ponder over this technique. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @botchedDevil: i havent seen that there are titles not separated by spaces. In this case, you can use a negative lookbehind, see my edit.